# Why is a class trivially copyable with all private special member functions?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, trivially-copyable

Code is like:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class A
{
    A() = default;
    A(const A&) = default;
    A(A&&) = default;
    A& operator=(const A&) = default;
    A& operator=(A&&) = default;
    ~A() = default;
    int a;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha <<
        std::is_trivially_copy_assignable_v<A> << " " <<
        std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<A> << " " <<
        std::is_trivially_move_assignable_v<A> << " " <<
        std::is_trivially_move_constructible_v<A> << " " <<
        std::is_trivially_destructible_v<A> << " " <<
        std::is_trivially_copyable_v<A> << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is `false false false false false true`. But according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes):

> A trivially copyable class is a class that
>
> - has at least one eligible copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator,
> - each eligible copy constructor is trivial
> - each eligible move constructor is trivial
> - each eligible copy assignment operator is trivial
> - each eligible move assignment operator is trivial, and
> - has a non-deleted trivial destructor.

So from the first four boolean outputs, none of the copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator and move assignment operator is trivial, so it's supposed to be non-trivially-copyable; However, the last output boolean is `true`.

Note: You can make `~A() = default` and `A() = default` public so that you can create objects, but the core question is still the same.

Comment: Just for completeness: Which compiler and standard version did you use?

Comment: @Sebastian I've tried gcc 12.2 and msvc 19.29. The standard version is C++20

Comment: @ALX23z Could you specify, how this requirement fits to the cited definition / standard wording?

Comment: @Sebastian you entered into a gray area. Something noone ever bothered checking as no one would ever use it. By making most of constructors/assignments private, the class is effectively non-usable. I don't think that writers of the standart considered such cases when they wrote it.

Comment: _from the first four boolean outputs, none of the copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator and move assignment operator is trivial_ This is not what `is_trivially...` traits check.

Comment: It seems the issue is caused by initially wrong wording in the standard that was addressed in [CWG 1734](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1734.html) but it seems it is still not implemented in both [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=98936) and [clang](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39050), and clang discussion mentions possible abi issues in case of the fix.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Err...It's quite oblique if a class's copy ctor is trivial while `std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v` is false.

Comment: _It's quite oblique if a class's copy ctor is trivial while `std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v` is false_ Why? It does not say `std::has_trivial_copy_constructor_v`, after all.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The question is not *can an instance of this class **actually** be copied*?

`std::is_trivially_copyable` answers

***if** you copied this instance with a bytewise copy, would the result be the same as copying using a copy operator*?

Answer (score 10):

`std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<T>` doesn't check whether `T` has a trivial copy constructor, which is what trivially-copyable is based on.

Instead it checks whether a definition of a variable of the form

```
T t(u);
```

where `u` is a variable of type `const T`, would be well-formed in a context unrelated to `T` and that the construction of the variable would use only trivial functions. This includes a check for accessibility and a check for a non-deleted accesible destructor.

The same applies in similar form to the other `_constructible_` and `_assignable_` traits. These traits are not directly related to `is_trivially_copyable`. The `is_trivially_copyable` trait tells you whether you can use `memcpy` to copy objects of the type. It doesn't tell you whether copy/move-construction/assignment will be possible and trivial, which is what the other traits are for.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the class `A` has an eligible move constructor that is **trivial**. Moreover, it also has a **trivial** non-deleted destructor and so class `A` satisfies all the requirement quoted below from [trivially copyable class](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.prop):

> A trivially copyable class is a class:
>
> - that has **at least one eligible** copy constructor, **move constructor**, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator
> - where each eligible copy constructor, **move constructor**, copy assignment operator, and move assignment
>   operator **is trivia**l, and
> - that has a **trivial, non-deleted destructor** (11.4.7).

(emphasis mine)

Note the emphasis on **at least** which means that class `A` satisfied all of the 3 above requirements.

---

The destructor is **trivial** as it is not user-provided and satisfied all 3 conditions given below:

> A destructor is **trivial if it is not user-provided** and if:
>
> - the destructor is not virtual
> - all of the direct base classes of its class have trivial destructors, and
> - for all of the non-static data members of its class that are of class type (or array thereof), each such
>   class has a trivial destructor.

---

Similarly, the move constructor is also trivial which is one of the requirements(the second one to be specific) for a trivially copyable class.

> A copy/move constructor for class X is **trivial if it is not user-provided** and if:
>
> - class X has no virtual functions (11.7.3) and no virtual base classes (11.7.2), and
> - the constructor selected to copy/move each direct base class subobject is trivial, and
> - for each non-static data member of X that is of class type (or array thereof), the constructor selected to
>   copy/move that member is trivial;

Comment: The problem is that, say, it reports that the destructor is not trivial according to type traits. So some of the reported values are definitely wrong.

Comment: @ALX23z I think you've mis-understood what first four traits mean.